# How to format date and time in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, time

I am trying to record the creation time, date of input data into a SQLite in Django in the format `Jan 1, 2021, 8:21 a.m.`. So far I can get the time to work doing the following in models.py:

```
class Listing(models.Model):
    time = models.TimeField(auto_now_add=True) 
    date = models.DateField() 
    def __str__(self):
        return f"({ ({self.time}))"
```

with my html:

```
{% block body %}

    <div>
                 <p> Started: {{listing.date}},{{listing.time}}</p>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

My views.py [note I've removed some additional that does not have to do with this question]:

```
def listing(request, name):
    listing = Listina.objects.get(listingTitle=name)
    return render(request, "auctions/listing.html", {
        "listing": listing,
    })
```

I get the following error:

```
Exception Type: OperationalError at /
Exception Value: no such column: auctions_listing.date
```

So I'm assuming it's because `date` in Listing is null. How can I fix this?

Comment: you've probably forgot to create and run migrations. `python manage.py makemigrations &&  python manage.py migrate`

Comment: Also, note that the output format has no relation to the database. Formatting should be only done in the template or view.

Comment: Thanks @AlexandrTatarinov... I tried to ```makemigrations``` and ```migrate```. It still gives me the error: ```OperationalError at / no such column: auctions_listing.date```

Answer (score 0):

I just made the field to `null = true`:

```
class Listing(models.Model):
    time = models.TimeField(auto_now_add=True) 
    date = models.DateField(null = true) 
    def __str__(self):
        return f"({ ({self.time}))"
```

Then ran `makemigrations` and `migrate`